# nfs4 and kerberos: Wrong principal in request

Tags: ubuntu, kerberos, nfs4, heimdal

My client/servers are both running Ubuntu 14.04 and kerberos user authentication works as intended. regular nfs4 mounts also work fine. All machines are running heimdal libraries.

I haven't been able to get kerberized nfs4 working though.

When mounting a share, I get the following entries in the logs:

## NFS4 Server:

```
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: leaving poll
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: handling null request
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: svcgssd_limit_krb5_enctypes: Calling gss_set_allowable_enctypes with 7 enctypes from the kernel
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: WARNING: gss_accept_sec_context failed
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: ERROR: GSS-API: error in handle_nullreq: gss_accept_sec_context(): GSS_S_FAILURE (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information) - Wrong principal in request
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: sending null reply
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: writing message: \x \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 1403429173 851968 2529639056 \x \x 
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: finished handling null request
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: entering poll
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: leaving poll
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: handling null request
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: svcgssd_limit_krb5_enctypes: Calling gss_set_allowable_enctypes with 7 enctypes from the kernel
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: WARNING: gss_accept_sec_context failed
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: ERROR: GSS-API: error in handle_nullreq: gss_accept_sec_context(): GSS_S_FAILURE (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information) - Wrong principal in request
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: sending null reply
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: writing message: \x \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 1403429173 851968 2529639056 \x \x 
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: finished handling null request
  Jun 22 11:25:13 SERVER rpc.svcgssd[7349]: entering poll
```

### Exportfs:

```
/srv XXX.XXX.209.0/24(fsid=0,rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                                          
/srv tip*.example.com(fsid=0,rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                               
/srv pclab*.example.com(fsid=0,rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                             
                                                                    
/srv/home XXX.XXX.209.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                                            
/srv/home tip*.example.com(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                                 
/srv/home pclab*.example.com(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                               
/srv/home XXX.XXX.208.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                                            
/srv/home wslab*.example.com(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                               
                                                                    
/srv/grpdrvs XXX.XXX.209.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                                         
/srv/grpdrvs tip*.example.com(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                              
/srv/grpdrvs pclab*.example.com(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)                            
/srv/grpdrvs XXX.XXX.208.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p)
```

### /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
XXX.XXX.209.52   SERVER.example.com      SERVER

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

## Server and client:

### /etc/idmapd:

```
[General]

Verbosity = 5
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = example.com
Local-Realms = REALM
[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

## NFS4 Client:

### Mount request:

```
  mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 SERVER:/ /mnt/temp/ -vvvv
  mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
  mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
  mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
  mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
  mount: UID:        0
  mount: eUID:       0
  mount: spec:  "SERVER:/"
  mount: node:  "/mnt/temp/"
  mount: types: "nfs4"
  mount: opts:  "sec=krb5"
  mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.nfs4"
  mount: external mount: argv[1] = "SERVER:/"
  mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/mnt/temp/"
  mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
  mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
  mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw,sec=krb5"
  mount.nfs4: timeout set for Sun Jun 22 11:24:33 2014
  mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.52,clientaddr=XXX.XXX.XXX.42'
  mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
  mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting SERVER:/
```

### Client logs:

```
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: handling gssd upcall (/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt0)
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: handle_gssd_upcall: 'mech=krb5 uid=0 enctypes=18,17,16,23,3,1,2 '
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: handling krb5 upcall (/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt0)
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: process_krb5_upcall: service is '<null>'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: Full hostname for 'SERVER.example.com' is 'SERVER.example.com'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: Full hostname for 'CLIENT.example.com' is 'CLIENT.example.com'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: No key table entry found for CLIENT$@REALM while getting keytab entry for 'CLIENT$@'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: No key table entry found for root/CLIENT.example.com@REALM while getting keytab entry for 'root/CLIENT.example.com@'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: Success getting keytab entry for 'nfs/CLIENT.example.com@'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM' are good until 1403514481
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM' are good until 1403514481
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: using FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM as credentials cache for machine creds
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: using environment variable to select krb5 ccache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: creating context using fsuid 0 (save_uid 0)
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: creating tcp client for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: DEBUG: port already set to 2049
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: creating context with server nfs@SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: WARNING: Failed to create krb5 context for user with uid 0 for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: WARNING: Failed to create machine krb5 context with credentials cache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: WARNING: Machine cache is prematurely expired or corrupted trying to recreate cache for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: Full hostname for 'SERVER.example.com' is 'SERVER.example.com'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: Full hostname for 'CLIENT.example.com' is 'CLIENT.example.com'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: No key table entry found for CLIENT$@REALM while getting keytab entry for 'CLIENT$@'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: No key table entry found for root/CLIENT.example.com@REALM while getting keytab entry for 'root/CLIENT.example.com@'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: Success getting keytab entry for 'nfs/CLIENT.example.com@'
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM' are good until 1403514481
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM' are good until 1403514481
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: using FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM as credentials cache for machine creds
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: using environment variable to select krb5 ccache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: creating context using fsuid 0 (save_uid 0)
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: creating tcp client for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: DEBUG: port already set to 2049
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: creating context with server nfs@SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: WARNING: Failed to create krb5 context for user with uid 0 for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: WARNING: Failed to create machine krb5 context with credentials cache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: WARNING: Failed to create machine krb5 context with any credentials cache for server SERVER.example.com
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: doing error downcall
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: destroying client /run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnte
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: destroying client /run/rpc_pipefs/nfsd4_cb/clntd
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: destroying client /run/rpc_pipefs/nfsd4_cb/clnt7
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: destroying client /run/rpc_pipefs/nfsd4_cb/clnt6
  Jun 22 11:25:13 CLIENT rpc.gssd[708]: destroying client /run/rpc_pipefs/nfsd4_cb/clnt5
```

### Client keytab:

```
% ktutil list                                                                                                             
FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab:

Vno  Type                     Principal                                     Aliases
  1  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  host/CLIENT.example.com@REALM 
  1  des3-cbc-sha1            host/CLIENT.example.com@REALM 
  1  arcfour-hmac-md5         host/CLIENT.example.com@REALM 
  1  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  nfs/CLIENT.example.com@REALM  
  1  des3-cbc-sha1            nfs/CLIENT.example.com@REALM  
  1  arcfour-hmac-md5         nfs/CLIENT.example.com@REALM
```

### Client credential cache:

```
% klist -c /tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM                                                            
Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM
    Principal: nfs/CLIENT.example.com@REALM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Jun 22 13:55:01 2014  Jun 23 13:55:01 2014  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
Jun 22 13:55:01 2014  Jun 23 13:55:01 2014  nfs/SERVER.example.com@REALM
```

### Client /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
XXX.XXX.209.17 CLIENT.example.com CLIENT
```

## DNS related:

### Reverse DNS:

```
% host XXX.XXX.209.17
17.209.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer CLIENT.example.com.
% host XXX.XXX.209.52
52.209.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer SERVER.example.com.
```

### getent hosts from SERVER:

```
root@SERVER:~# getent hosts CLIENT.example.com
XXX.XXX.209.17   CLIENT.example.com
root@SERVER:~# getent hosts SERVER.example.com
XXX.XXX.209.52   SERVER.example.com SERVER
```

### getent hosts from CLIENT:

```
CLIENT 00:03:32 # getent hosts SERVER.example.com
XXX.XXX.209.52   SERVER.example.com
CLIENT 00:03:41 # getent hosts CLIENT.example.com
XXX.XXX.209.17   CLIENT.example.com CLIENT
```

I have been debugging this issue for weeks, but I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: Please add the `/etc/exports` configuration.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using an `fsid=0`, check that the `sec=` configuration is correct, too.

Comment: I added the exports.

Comment: Is name resolution working OK? (i.e., what's the output of `dig SERVER.example.com` and `dig CLIENT.example.com`?) Are you using local resolution or a DNS?

Comment: I'm using DNS resolution. The /etc/hosts for the respective machines have 127.0.0.1 pointing to localhost and also have their IP pointing to their hostnames.
'hostname -f' gives the FQDN for both machines.
Dig also shows the correct IPs for all involved machines.

Comment: If you do the same for reverse DNS resolution these all match too right?

Comment: According to [this](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/princ_dns.html), and [this](http://www.es.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kerberos5.html), "All hosts in your realm must be resolvable (both forwards and reverse)" @MatthewIfe you beat me to it

Comment: The Client:`% host XXX.XXX.209.17
    17.209.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer CLIENT.example.com.`
And the Server:
    `% host XXX.XXX.209.52
    52.209.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer SERVER.example.com.`

All resolve correctly. The error points to a DNS problem, but if it indeed is one, I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution:

Looking at an strace of the rpc.svcgssd daemon, I saw that the last file opened before the error ways the `/etc/krb5.keytab`.

The keytab on the server was generated using `kadmin` with a kinit of "kadmin/admin".

A `kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab nfs/SERVER.example.com@REALM` on the SERVER resulted in a invalid password errror. So i deleted the keytab and generated a new one using `kadmin -l`. There might be a problem with the keytab of my `kadmin/admin` user that resulted in a corrupt keytab. I haven't investigaed the problem yet.

After I created a new keytab, the nfs4+krb5 mount succeeded.

Thank your for your answers, they helped a lot in narrowing the problem down.

So for anyone encountering a similiar problem:

1. Try to `kinit` the service tickets on every invovled host using `kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab nfs/SERVER.example.com@REALM`
2. Do a `strace -p $(pidof rpc.svcgssd) -s4096 -e trace=open,close,read,write` and check what is happening before the error occurs.
3. From all I have read, the "Wrong Principal" error usually occurs if the machines have a mapping to `127.0.0.1` for their hostname.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update - it's much appreciated as this'll be a reference point for others in future.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a syntax marked as DEPRECATED in the `exports(5)` manpage:

```
RPCSEC_GSS security
   You may use the special strings "gss/krb5", "gss/krb5i", or "gss/krb5p" to restrict
   access to clients using rpcsec_gss security.  However, this syntax is deprecated; on
   linux kernels  since  2.6.23,  you  should instead use the "sec=" export option:

   sec=   The  sec=  option,  followed  by a colon-delimited list of security flavors, restricts the export to clients using those flavors.  Available security flavors include sys (the default--no cryptographic secu‐
          rity), krb5 (authentication only), krb5i (integrity protection), and krb5p (privacy protection).  For the purposes of security flavor negotiation, order counts: preferred flavors  should  be  listed  first.
          The  order  of  the  sec=  option  with respect to the other options does not matter, unless you want some options to be enforced differently depending on flavor.  In that case you may include multiple sec=
          options, and following options will be enforced only for access using flavors listed in the immediately preceding sec= option.  The only options  that  are  permitted  to  vary  in  this  way  are  ro,  rw,
          no_root_squash, root_squash, and all_squash.
```

So your exports should be:

```
/srv      XXX.XXX.209.0/24(fsid=0,rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5)
/srv/home XXX.XXX.209.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5)
```

It is important that both the `fsid=0` and the exported resource have the correct security configuration. Choose the appropriate `krb5/krb5i/krb5p` for your setup.

The error "Wrong principal in request" can be caused by wrong name resolution. If you are using local resolution, inspect your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: I've changed the syntax and updated my post to reflect the changes, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

People dealing with problems like this, usually do:

1. DNS names *and* FQDN of your hosts must be lowercase, even if your DNS supports Uppercase in FQDN.
2. You should have a principal named like your machine name, in example: `SERVER1$@YOUR.REALM.NAME`, and add to keytab accordingly (all UPERCASE and ending with `$`)
3. You should have principals `host/your-machine.your.domain.name` and `nfs/your-machine.your.domain.name`, and add this principal to keytab accordingly.
4. Your `/etc/hosts` must not have uppercases names, and FQDN should be firsts than short name if any.